# label.visible = true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

The visible function doesnt work, but why? Is a true set in a callback not allowed?. When I set the visible to true on top of the page(`_Default : System.Web.UI.Page`)  it is working.

```
information_remedyID.Visible = true;
information_remedyID.Text = inquiryId;
```

TOP Class:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
.......
    private static string inquiryId;     

......

private void InsertIncidentCallback(server3.ILTISAPI api, IAsyncResult result, string username, string msg_id)
        {
            string message;
            api.EndInsertIncident(result, out message);

            if (message == null)
            {
                string responseXML;
                api.REMEDY_ReadResponseXML(username, out responseXML, out msg_id);
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseXML);
                inquiryId = (string)doc.Root.Element("inquiry_id");

                if (inquiryId == null | inquiryId == "")
                {
                    information_text.Text = "....";
                }
                else
                {
                    information_remedyID.Visible = true;
                    information_remedyID.Text = inquiryId;
                    //create_LanDesk(computer_idn, swidn_choice, swName_choice, inquiryId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                information_text.Visible = true;
                information_text.Text = "...";
            }
        }
}
```

asp:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Willkommen im BISS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span style="font-size: 16pt"><strong>BISS<br />
        </strong><span style="font-size: 12pt">
            <br />
            Angemeldet als:
            <asp:Label ID="user_id" runat="server" Text="user_id"></asp:Label><br />
            Hostname:
            <asp:Label ID="hostname_id" runat="server" Text="hostname_id"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            CI Nummer:
            <asp:Label ID="CI_NR" runat="server" Text="CI_NR"></asp:Label></span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="softwarelist" runat="server" DataTextField="SoftwareName" DataValueField="SoftwareName">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Bitte Software auswählen" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp; 
            <asp:Button ID="requestbt" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Software zuweisen" /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="information_text" runat="server" Text="information_text" Visible="False"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="information_remedyID" runat="server" Text="information_remedyID" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never use static fields in ASP.NET if you don't want that all users share the same value. Get into the habit of using local variables instead.

Comment: that may be because of callback will be called after page is rendered in browser

Comment: the callback is used, when a user click on a button.

Comment: Is there a container control around that `information_remedyID` label, with Visible=false? If the container is not visible, all controls inside it are invisible.

Comment: so it never show the text from information_remedyID when the Site does not a reload, cause the callback is a background thread?!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a UpdatePanel with UpdateMode="Conditional"

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProfileEditingUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

---

In case you use WPF

```
information_remedyID.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

- Sorry, overread ASP!

Comment: plz add your html source code as well..i think it may be the problem of update panel.so plz put your html code as well..

Comment: I debugged through the code and the visbile set true, but nothing show.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (inquiryId == null | inquiryId == "")
```

If this should be an or change it to a double stripe:

```
if (inquiryId == null || inquiryId == "")
```

Comment: So it's just a typo in the post?

Comment: Yes, you need a double stripe: ||

Answer (score 0):

Use a UpdatePanel, like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Willkommen</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>    
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <span style="font-size: 16pt">
            <strong>
                BISS<br />
            </strong>
            <span style="font-size: 12pt">
                <br />
                Angemeldet als:
                <asp:Label ID="user_id" runat="server" Text="user_id"></asp:Label><br />
                Hostname:
                <asp:Label ID="hostname_id" runat="server" Text="hostname_id"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                CI Nummer:
                <asp:Label ID="CI_NR" runat="server" Text="CI_NR"></asp:Label></span></span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="softwarelist" runat="server" DataTextField="SoftwareName" DataValueField="SoftwareName">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Bitte Software auswählen" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp; 
                <asp:Button ID="requestbt" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Software zuweisen" /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="information_text" runat="server" Text="information_text" Visible="False"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="information_remedyID" runat="server" Text="information_remedyID" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And in your code, after you changed the visibility:

```
MyUpdatePanel.Update();
```

Comment: is that the only option? I got a error "Unkown Servertag asp:UpdatePanel"

Comment: You would need a ScriptManager to handle it as well

You might go throuh the tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb398864%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: And yes, you need a UpdatePanel! The html is static, and the browser doesn't know, if you change something on your server, so you need to tell the browser that there has been changes and force it to reload, a browser doesn't observer changes on its own!

Comment: but I have maybe a other solution. I make the message as a global variable, make a waithandle for the callback and create a other single method with the if message and make there the api.REMEDY_ReadResponseXML to get the remedyID.

Comment: If it works, use it! But the UpdatePanel exists also in 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work either. 
A workaround is to use `Style="display: none;"` instead of `Visible="False"`. Then you can reveal it with 
`information_remedyID.Style["display"] = "initial";`